# How do I manually configure the DNS of my tethered connection?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, tethering, dns

In my new moto E, tethering my internet connection isn't working. I configured my nexus tablet to use my mobile phone connection. Everything looks fine, it looks like it is connected, but I can't access anything.

Using a terminal app, I can successfully ping a domain with numbers: ping 8.8.8.8, but when I try to point a domain name (Google.com), it fails.

I've tried with other devices and the result is the same.

How do I manually configure the DNS of my tethered connection?

Any other suggestion to fix this problem is welcome.

Some tests that I did:

- I tested tethering with two android devices, and both had the same problem.
- These devices used to successfully "theter" in my old Moto G.
- The problem happens in wifi and usb tethering.
- A few apps work fine, like WhatsApp. I believe they use the IP Address directly.

The moto E has Android 5.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed the DNSet app and it solved my tethering Moto E bug. The pro version allow you to configure any DNS server, but it wasn't necessary.